# Bootstrap 3: Navbar doesnt collapse into hamburguer menu when screen is shrinked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap 3` and for some reason my `navbar` menu doesn't collapse into the "hamburger" menu when I shrink the screen.

I have checked that I have included JQuery and both the Bootstrap Javascript and CSS files. The console isn't throwing any errors either.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>My Site</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yesteryear' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/thumbnail-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body style="background-color:#F0F0F0;">


    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="font-family:YesterYear; font-size:2.9em;">MY SITE</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="font-size:1.5em;" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is malformed `<a href="#"></i></a>` is wrong `<a href="# target="blank">` is wrong - check the syntax

Comment: also close the "#" here : <a href="# target="blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

Comment: I'm afraid those errors where just me crewing up the code when pasting it to stackoverflow. Sorry. @Gijsberts answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify a style to your navbar. change `<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">`. It will create the hamburger menu for you. Then, you have to style your nav bar.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/13p6um3w/

I found some typos in your code (unclosed quotes, tags)

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="font-size:2.9em;">MY SITE</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="font-size:1.5em; color: black;" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="blank">l1<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">l2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="blank">l3<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="blank">l4<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```